# SharePoint Online Threshold Error after Uploading file and modifying column values (SpFx)

Tags: file-upload, sharepoint-online, spfx, pnp-js

We are facing issue in update of Library column values post upload of file. This issue has started occurring once the record in library exceeded 5,000 items.

Please share a code sample which works with library having more than 5,000 items most resources are available for library having less than 5,000 items;

Sample Resource: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/file-upload-and-metadata-updation-in-spfx-with-pnpjsreact

Error occurs on line: f.file.getItem().then(item => {

```
.files.add(fileName, element.content, true)
      .then(f => {
        f.file.getItem().then(item => {
```

In the console this URL is shown: /_api/web/getFolderByServerRelativeUrl('')/files()/listItemAllFields

Answer (score 0):

I tested above code snippet in a demo SPFx web part with a large library(over 7000 items) but works fine.

```
const file = await sp.web.getFolderByServerRelativeUrl("/sites/sbdev/My test doc lib/docs").files.add(filename, fileContent, true);
    const item = await file.file.getItem();
    await item.update({
      Title: "A Title"+ (new Date()).toLocaleDateString(),
      uuId: 18
    });
```

Please take a reference of the below sample:

- https://github.com/kongmengfei/SharedSPFx/blob/main/pnpjsuploadfiles/src/webparts/pnpjsuploadfiles/components/Pnpjsuploadfiles.tsx
- https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/sp/files/#setting-associated-item-values

BR